# Command for returning transactions in json format to external code

Tags: transaction-data, python

I want to iterate (from a Python program) over all the outputs of all the transactions on the blockchain.
Is there any RCP command or something like that, that returns a structure of transactions as is and not their hashes?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html

Documents all the API methods you would need.

You would first use [get_block_count](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_count) then iterate calling [get_block](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block), then calling [get_transactions](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) with the returned `tx_hashes` from `get_block`.

Comment: It's great, thanks!
Do you know how to see transaction's outputs? because get_transactions doesn't show me outputs (amount and key), the only output related data is "output_indices'.

Comment: Add `"decode_as_json":true` to the request.

Comment: I'v done that, but when I do nothing is showing up.

this is the code that show me json:
  response = requests.post(
        "http://localhost:28081/gettransactions",
        data=json.dumps({"txs_hashes": all_tx_hashes}),
        headers=headers)             
    print(response.content)

and this code show nothing:
   response = requests.post(
        "http://localhost:28081/gettransactions",
        data=json.dumps({"txs_hashes": all_tx_hashes,"decode_as_json":'true'}),
        headers=headers)             
    print(response.content)

Comment: `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:28081/get_transactions -d '{"txs_hashes":["80ba003b5115a66e3aa77b6e6d4c8d5ef71e8a9806b4a9a1c69dc4c3f325251e"],"decode_as_json":true}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json` works fine for me.